# Scrapy Parse function not passing found values to the parse_page2 function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape playstation webstore to scrape title, gamelink from the main page and Price for each game from the second page. However when using callback function to parse_page2, all the returned items contain the title and item['link'] value of the most recent item. (last of us remastered )

My code Below:

```
class PsStoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'psstore'
    start_urls =['https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/pages/browse']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = PlaystationItem()
        products = response.css('a.psw-link')
 
        for product in products:

            item['main_url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = product.css('span.psw-t-body.psw-c-t-1.psw-t-truncate-2.psw-m-b-2::text').get()
            item['link'] = 'https://store.playstation.com' + product.css('a.psw-link.psw-content-link').attrib['href']
            link = 'https://store.playstation.com' + product.css('a.psw-link.psw-content-link').attrib['href']

            request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['price'] = response.css('span.psw-t-title-m::text').get()
        item['other_url'] = response.url
        yield item
```

And part of the output:

```
2022-05-09 19:54:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/229261> 
{'link': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/228638',
 'main_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/pages/browse',
 'other_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/229261',
 'price': 'Free',
 'title': 'The Last of Us™ Remastered'}
2022-05-09 19:54:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/232847> 
{'link': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/228638',
 'main_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/pages/browse',
 'other_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/232847',
 'price': '€59.99',
 'title': 'The Last of Us™ Remastered'}
2022-05-09 19:54:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/224802> (referer: https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/pages/browse)
2022-05-09 19:54:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/224802> 
{'link': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/228638',
 'main_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/pages/browse',
 'other_url': 'https://store.playstation.com/en-ie/concept/224802',
 'price': '€29.99',
 'title': 'The Last of Us™ Remastered'}
```

As you can see the price is correctly returned but title and link are taken from the last scraped object. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you create your `item` at the beginning of your parse method and then update it over and over. That also means that you always pass the same item to `parse_page2`.
If you were to create your item in the `for`-loop you would get a new one in every iteration and should get the expected result.
Like this:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('a.psw-link')
 
        for product in products:
            item = PlaystationItem()
            item['main_url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = product.css('span.psw-t-body.psw-c-t-1.psw-t-truncate-2.psw-m-b-2::text').get()
            item['link'] = 'https://store.playstation.com' + product.css('a.psw-link.psw-content-link').attrib['href']
            link = 'https://store.playstation.com' + product.css('a.psw-link.psw-content-link').attrib['href']

            request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so Much!